# MongoDB query sort with unique

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection which holds competition results.

```
{"person" : "Adam",  "time" : 10.01, "compName" : "comp A"}
{"person" : "Bob",   "time" : 10.12, "compName" : "comp B"}
{"person" : "Adam",  "time" : 9.03,  "compName" : "comp C"}
{"person" : "Adam",  "time" : 10.99, "compName" : "comp D"}
{"person" : "David", "time" : 10.05, "compName" : "comp D"}
{"person" : "Bob",   "time" : 10.78, "compName" : "comp E"}
```

I'm trying to get rankings from this collection.

I've tried doing `db.results.find({}).sort({"time" : 1})`, however this gives me duplicates results for the same name. How can I get only the best time for each name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use mongodb [aggregation $min](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/#grp._S_min) to accomplish that

Your query will be something like the following

```
db.results.aggregate(
   {$group: {_id: '$person', besttime: {$min: "$time"}}}
   {$sort: {besttime: 1}}
);
```

Regarding meteor, I believe that's a separate question you need to ask depending on your issue with it.

EDIT:

If you want to use the `compName` also as an aggregation value, just add it to the `$group` hash like

```
db.results.aggregate(
   {$group: {_id: '$person', "compName": { "$first": "$compName" }, besttime: {$min: "$time"}}}, 
   {$sort: {besttime: 1}}
);
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep the `compName` the min time came from?

Comment: @OrangePeel just added to the `$group` hash. I edited the answer with an example

Comment: @chridam Oh, sure, that's correct if the answer needs just one name regardless of the `compName`. Reading through the querstion now, I believe that's exactly what is wanted... Editing my answer now, thanks

Comment: Sorry, I meant the compName that corresponds to the min time. E.g. for `Adam`, the min time of `9.03` would correspond to compName `comp C`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `$min` or `$max` below as required,

```
db.results.aggregate(
   [
      {
        $group : {
           "_id": "$person",
           "time":  { "$min": "$time" },
           "compName": { $push: "compName" }
         }
      }
   ]
)
```